# Flutter IndexedStack alternative

Tags: flutter, dart

is there any alternative for something like `IndexedStack` on flutter? I used `IndexedStack` before but my WebView app feels slower and sometimes crashes on some devices. Someone in [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54810#issuecomment-614476743) says that cause using `IndexedStack` and `SetState`. Is there any solution to avoid crashes and increase the WebView performance? For your information, I using the [InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package in this case.

I wanna show a loading screen like this when `onLoadStart`, then show the WebView page when `onLoadStop`.

[image]

here is my sample app code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class SimpleWebiew extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleWebiewState createState() => _SimpleWebiewState();
}

class _SimpleWebiewState extends State<SimpleWebiew> {
  num _stackToView = 1;
  InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Simple WebView'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _stackToView,
        children: [
          Opacity(
            opacity: _stackToView == 0 ? 1 : 0,
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                url: Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev/'),
              ),
              onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                _webViewController = controller;
              },
              onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: (controller, _challenge) async {
                return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
                  action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED,
                );
              },
              initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                  allowContentAccess: true,
                  builtInZoomControls: true,
                  thirdPartyCookiesEnabled: true,
                  allowFileAccess: true,
                  geolocationEnabled: true,
                  supportMultipleWindows: true,
                ),
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
                  useOnDownloadStart: true,
                  allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
                  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true,
                ),
              ),
              onLoadStart: (inAppWebViewController, uri) {
                setState(() {
                  _stackToView = 1;
                });
              },
              onLoadStop: (inAppWebViewController, uri) {
                setState(() {
                  _stackToView = 0;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duythien0912/flutter_zalo_login/master/flutter.jpeg',
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 200.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Connecting to server ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AnimatedSwitcher too : [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g)

AnimatedSwitcher is similar to IndexedStack so IDK if that will help but try it first.

Or you just use inline if statement to achieve what you want. like this:

```
bool _isLoading = true;
...
_isLoading ? LoadingWidget : WebView
```

if it is loading, LoadingWidget will be shown, otherwise the WebView will be shown.

And the debug version will always be slow. Try it on release version with: `flutter run --release`